# Dissmiss modal controller triggered Segue in Swift/Objc hybrid project

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have a situation that I'm not sure how to handle correctly.  As you see in the picture below I have a Table View Controller, I have a Modal Popup and another View Controller.

[image]

What I'm trying to do is when the user clicks a button on the left most TableView controller a pop up will display via a Modal Segue.  Once dismissed the the Navigation Controller will transfer to the Right ViewController

Initial View Controller
 * Button Pressed Segue Modal

Swift Modal Controller
 * Presses button and calls `self.dismissViewControlelr`

But then what happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you'd like to have the navigation controller perform a push segue after a presented view controller dismisses itself.

There are a couple ways to go about it, but I think simplest is to have the presented view controller (the "swift modal") post a notification from within the completion block of the dismiss function.

The vc contained by the navigation controller should then perform the push segue upon receiving this notification.

Comment: Ah ... i will try that tomorrow.  The notificaiton thing didn't cross my mind.